Export table to a XLSX file in React
I am displaying a simple HTML table and have an export to Excel button. I found an easy to use React component called react-export-table-to-excel. It works perfectly, except I need it to be an XLSX file, not an XLS file. All the React components I have found are from spreadJS, or SheetsJS. The problem is they are premium frameworks and our product owner will not approve them. All I need here is to export it to a XLSX file. I'm not embedding it in the browser.
